# Django form wizard - passing request to the view?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

Is there any way of accessing the `request` variable in the done() method of a Form Wizard?

```
class AddWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        if form_list[0].cleaned_data['ad_type'] == '1':
            ad_type = 'basic'
        else:
            ad_type = 'other'
        return render_to_response('business/done.html', {
            'form_data': ad_type,
            },
            context_instance = RequestContext(request)
        )
```

I want to access the user object that is in the request, but I am not sure how would I go about passing the request to the done() method?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. `SessionWizardView` extends the base generic `View` so the request is available in `self.request`.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering